# Command line (cmd) execution problems with PHP

Tags: php, shell, yii, command-line

I have tried to run a very simple PHP code to open a program in my PC called "Cyberghost". inside this code i have used shell_exec and exec as the following

```
<?php
echo  shell_exec('cyberghost /wait ');
echo  shell_exec('whoami');
echo  exec('cyberghost /wait ');
echo  exec('whoami');
?>
```

The First command have not been executed and the program haven't been opened. but the second command works perfectly and returned (ahmed\ahmed saleh ahmed\ahmed saleh) which is perfectly right.

Any idea about how to solve this problem ?

[edited] Note: I added Cyberghost path to the environmental variables path. and when i use the if condition, it shows that all the commands have been executed successfully.

Comment: is cyberghost in the path of the shell that's being opened? I'm guessing not. try `shell_exec('"c:\program files\whatever\cyberghost" /wait')` instead.

Comment: What error are you getting from the failed execution?

Comment: @Mark B: yes I added cyberghost to the path in the  environmental variables. And it works perfectly in the command line without the complete path

Comment: @Mureinik: I don't get any error. And when I use the if condition it does that the command has been excited successfully. While it doesn't open the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found an answer for my questions.

So I have to mention first that the details which have been stated above is just a simple version of my main problem. I was trying to create a program which change the IP address via cyberghost and then open a URL which is only valid in USA. 
While executing the following cyberghost command line: 
     cyberghost /connect /wait

it shows that the command have been executed successfully before changing your IP address. the change happens after around 20 seconds so my task was always failing to open the USA URL.

To solve this, you need to execute a command line which waits for 20 seconds (atleast)